# CPQ Parent to Child (Template Content to Quote Template)

Tags: soql, managed-package, cpq

I am trying to select child records (Quote Template) from the Parent (Template Content). I am not 100% sure what is wrong here:

Child relationship name : QuoteTemplatesFooter;
Parent object: SBQQ__TemplateContent__c

```
select id,
(select id from QuoteTemplatesFooter__r)
from SBQQ__TemplateContent__c
```

Error:`Didn't understand relationship 'QuoteTemplatesFooter__r' in FROM part of query call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship names that are part of managed packages include the package's namespace, as both fields and objects do. If you've validated that the relationship name is `QuoteTemplatesFooter` by inspecting the relationship field on the child object, you'd need to use

```
SELECT Id,
(SELECT Id FROM SBQQ__QuoteTemplatesFooter__r)
FROM SBQQ__TemplateContent__c
```